# AX2012 - Get new primary table field value by creation

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

i have a form with two grids. Each grid has it own datasource.
For more information look at the attached picture.

On dependence which line i select in the first grid, the content of the second grid will change.

Now my problem:
If i create a new row on the first grid, i am not able to enter values in the second grid because ax don't give me a new "combinationID" (Primary field, INT)

[image]

How can i solve this?

Comment: How are you populating combination id in first grid? Is it by number sequence? In any case after super in insert method of the first grid table,  insert a new record in second grid table with the combination id as in first grid table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a parent-child form where the upper grid is your "header" and the lower is your "lines".

If `CombinationID` is your primary key, it should probably be generated via number sequence or unique somehow.

On the form, the DataSource `MDISSearchDimensions`'s property `JoinSource` should be set to `MDISAccountSearchTerms`. It will use the table relation, but you need to specify they're joined.

Then once your `CombinationID` is set from the header, you just need to make sure the lines get it.  On the table `MDISSearchDimensions`, add a method called `initFromMDISAccountSearchTerms(MDISAccountSearchTerms _MDISAccountSearchTerms)`, which sets the `CombinationID` and call this method inside `MDISSearchDimensions.initValue()`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i make a number sequence for CombinationID. I use following steps https://community.dynamics.com/gp/b/dynamics101trainingcentergp/archive/2014/09/24/creating-custom-number-sequences-in-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012

Comment: when i create a new line the system show me a message which says: "A new number cannot be assigned because CS01-00001 has not been saved or deleted." When i open & close the form or press Ctrl+S it work fine. Is there a way to auto save the row?

Comment: Try this https://dynamicsuser.net/ax/f/developers/84652/solution-to-solve-number-sequence-problem-for-the-error-a-new-number-cannot-be-assigned-because-has-not-been-saved-or-deleted

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the `InsertIfEmpty` property of the second datasource.

The `initValue` method of the second datasource initializes the `CombinationId` field (provided proper relations) to the master `CombinationId` datasource value, but now it does so before the master datasource field has a value.

You have another option if want to leave it on; set it manually in `validateWrite` of the second datasource:

```
public boolean validateWrite()
{;
     MDISAccountDimension.CombinationId = MDISAccountSearchTerms.CombinationId;
     return super();
}
```

Thus it will no longer fail due to `Mandatory` being set.

You should hide the `CombinationId` in the second grid to avoid user errors.